# Chrome developer tools: Capture scripts from submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome-devtools, form-submit

I need to do some modifications on a submit form, for which it's needed that I first get it's complete source.

In Chrome Developer Tools it's easy to get the complete HTML and CSS.

Only problem is how to get the script source that makes the form work.

If you go to Developer Tools > Network > I see all sources. There are some script sources with a lot of codes for other things on the site, not directly responsible for this submit form. But I can select some source files that even show POST request for this form, when clicking on the source file > clicking headers. When I click on Preview I see a small fragment of a script code, but it seems to short in my opinion to make it work. But maybe I look on the wrong place.

What is normally the way in Chrome Developer Tools to capture the entire script source connected to a submit form?

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot?

Comment: @ArseniProkharchyk do you mean this? http://prnt.sc/aam2ow

Comment: I mean the devtools with marked place, where you are looking for script code

Comment: ah, I understand. I hope this clarifies something more for you @ArseniProkharchyk? http://prnt.sc/aaqybx
Otherwise let me know. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: OK, what you are seeing is the response on your request. And what exactly would you like to find? The javascript file which triggered this POST request? Or something different?

Comment: I want to make a copy of this form (which I don't have, that's why my question). I can easily copy the HTML and CSS to make it LOOK like this form. But then I have an exact copy of the form that will not function. Also a thing why I ask this question, is because there is a difference between source and source. You have source that links to external scripts, but I need to download all source to my computer, and then preferably that source that is needed to let this form function, including script code that handles the POST request of the submit button. Thanks in advance @ArseniProkharchyk

Comment: it's a via-via generated form (as part of a bigger script on my site), that's why the specific script source is unknown for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105343/discussion-between-arseni-prokharchyk-and-cinzel).